# In sublime text3 I want a 2 column layout with code on one side and the browser display on the other

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've seen tutorials where the code is in one column and the display in the other as in the attached image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is just TextWrangler and Chrome, not maximized. You can place the cursor at the edge of the window, then click and drag to resize to the desired layout.

Comment: oops I don't know why I assumed it was sublime text other tutotials that do use sublime text do I think, but now not so sure, have a browser display within sublime text.

Comment: Absence of evidence is not absence of evidence but I have never seen a browser running within a ST tab nor heard of anyone doing so. It seems to be something that is more trouble than it is worth given the ease of just tiling the ST window and the browser window together on the desktop as described by skuroda and shown in the example you provided.

Comment: @jimeast ST does not support an embedded browser within the editor.  If that is something you feel you need,  you may want to investigate atom by the folks at github.  The views are much more customizable in that editor.